# Connecting a real wsdl service and using its methods with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have an ecommerce website which is under development right now. I bought a web software. I want to connect to the webservice and add some brands.

This is my webservice **WSDL** url: http://www.cantabu.com/Servis/UrunServis.svc?wsdl

The method for adding a new brand is "**SaveMarka**".

This is my initial code:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$wsdl = "http://www.cantabu.com/Servis/UrunServis.svc?wsdl";
$authCode = "MY_WEBSERVICE_AUTHENTICATION_CODE";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
```

When i print_r **$client->__getFunctions()** The result is (Related to SaveMarka method):

```
Array
(
    [4] => SaveMarkaResponse SaveMarka(SaveMarka $parameters)
)
```

And when i print_r **$client->__getTypes()**, the result is (Up to 5th index of the result array, because others are unrelated to SaveMarka):

```
Array
(
    [0] => struct ArrayOfint {
 int int;
}
    [1] => struct ArrayOfstring {
 string string;
}
    [2] => struct ArrayOfKategori {
 Kategori Kategori;
}
    [3] => struct Kategori {
 boolean Aktif;
 int ID;
 string Icerik;
 string Kod;
 int PID;
 string SeoAnahtarKelime;
 string SeoSayfaAciklama;
 string SeoSayfaBaslik;
 int Sira;
 string Tanim;
}
    [4] => struct ArrayOfMarka {
 Marka Marka;
}
    [5] => struct Marka {
 boolean Aktif;
 int ID;
 string SeoAnahtarKelime;
 string SeoSayfaAciklama;
 string SeoSayfaBaslik;
 string Tanim;
}
```

**In their web service document, they say; if you want to add a new brand, the ID should be 0 (zero). Otherwise, whe webservice will update the brand related to that ID.**

I have tried different variations of SaveMarka method. But they all failed with varied results.

First of all, i have created a Marka class.

```
 class Marka{
      var $ID;
      var $SeoAnahtarKelime;
      var $SeoSayfaBaslik;
      var $SeoSayfaAciklama;
      var $Tanim;
      var $Aktif;


      function __construct($id, $seo, $seoAciklama, $seoBaslik, $ad){
          $this->ID = $id;
          $this->SeoAnahtarKelime = $seo;
          $this->SeoSayfaBaslik = $seoBaslik;
          $this->SeoSayfaAciklama = $seoAciklama;
          $this->Tanim = $ad;
          $this->Aktif = true;
      }
  }
```

Then i have tried to do this:

```
$marka = new Marka(0, "pg", "P&G", "P&G", "P&G");
$newMarka = array(
      "UyeKodu" => $authCode",
      "Marka" => $marka
);
$client->__soapCall("SaveMarka", $newMarka);
```

The result is:

> Type: SoapFault
>
> Message: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize
>   the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for
>   operation 'SaveMarka'. End element 'Body' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element
>   'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 150.

I also tried (I don't know why):

```
$marka = new Marka(0, "pg", "P&G", "P&G", "P&G");
$newMarka = array(array(
      "UyeKodu" => $authCode",
      "Marka" => $marka
));
$client->__soapCall("SaveMarka", $newMarka);
```

And the result is:

> Type: SoapFault
>
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Then i get rid of the Marka class and tried to do it simpler without using a class:

```
 $newMarka = array(
      "UyeKodu" => $authCode,
      "ID" => 0,
      "Tanim" => "P&G",
      "Aktif" => true,
      "SeoAnahtarKelime" => "pg",
      "SeoSayfaBaslik" => "P&G",
      "SeoSayfaAciklama" => "P&G"
 );
 $client->__soapCall("SaveMarka", $newMarka);
```

Result is:

> Type: SoapFault
>
> Message: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize
>   the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for
>   operation 'SaveMarka'. End element 'Body' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element
>   'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 150.

And also (again, i don't know why)

```
 $newMarka = array(array(
      "UyeKodu" => $authCode,
      "ID" => 0,
      "Tanim" => "P&G",
      "Aktif" => true,
      "SeoAnahtarKelime" => "pg",
      "SeoSayfaBaslik" => "P&G",
      "SeoSayfaAciklama" => "P&G"
 ));
 $client->__soapCall("SaveMarka", $newMarka);
```

And the result is:

> Type: SoapFault
>
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am i doing wrong?

Can anyone please help me with adding a new brand? I have supplied the functions, types, wsdl link and all my tries.

Please, help.

Comment: Have you tried serialising the object when passing it in as a parameter to soapCall?

Comment: @trickyzter What do you mean? How do i do that in PHP?

Comment: Sorry ignore that comment. Do you have a link to the documentation for the web service?

Comment: Of course, but it's in Turkish. http://www.ticimax.com/dokumanlar/webservis.pdf The content related to SaveMarka is on page 3. It's for C# i think.

Comment: Remove the constructor method and set the properties publicly, also pass the parameters in using a standalone array and not var. i.e. $client->__soapCall("SaveMarka", array());

Comment: Additionally when using soapCall you need to wrap the params in an additional array. i.e. $client->__soapCall("SaveMarka", array(array()));